# How Can I Have a Data Binding Expression React To Changes In an EditText In the Same Layout?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Suppose that I have an `EditText` with an ID of `foo`. Elsewhere in the same layout resource, I have a `Button`, and I want to enable the `Button` only if there is text in the `EditText`.

I thought that this would work:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{listener}"
            android:text="Um, hi!"
            android:enabled="@{foo.text.length > 0}" />
```

The generated binding class does indeed call `setEnabled()` on `bar` based on the length of the text in `foo`... but only when `executeBindings()` is called. That does not seem to be called as the user types, so the enabled state of my `Button` does not change based on the user entering text in the `EditText`.

I can work around this, but it feels like this should be working. Is there something that I'm missing? Is this a known limitation?

Comment: If you want your layout/view react to dynamic changes, you should use `ObservableField`, `Observable` or `LiveData` field: using two-way binding save text from `EditText` in such variable, and after that your button state will be changed (if you connect button state to such `ObservableField`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

Just change `foo.text.length` to `foo.text.length()`.

---

#### Old Solution

Some points, perhaps which you missed.

#### 1. Using `BaseObservable`

If your `model` `extends` `BaseObservable` then you need to make `food.text`     `@Bindable`.

```
public class UserBaseObservable extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }
}
```

**Reason** being, when you use `text.length` then you need to invoke all dependent elements when it is changed. Because `text.length` is not observable, so you need to manually invoke it. Generated binding class calls `setName(value)` but it does not change `text.length` dependent views.

#### 2. Using `MutableLiveData`

If you use `MutableLiveData` then it is nessesary to provide `LifeCycleOwner`

```
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

#### 3. Using `ObservableField` (Shortest approach)

Another easy approach is to use `ObservableField` for `foo.text`

**I said easy** because you don't need to make this field `Bindable` in this case.

```
public class UserObservableField {
    private ObservableField<String> name = new ObservableField<>();

    public ObservableField<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(ObservableField<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### I created a sample with 3 of these solutions, all are working!

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <data>

        <variable
            name="userObservableField"
            type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.activities.LoginActivity.UserObservableField"/>

        <variable
            name="userMutable"
            type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.activities.LoginActivity.UserMutable"/>

        <variable
            name="userBaseObservable"
            type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.activities.LoginActivity.UserBaseObservable"/>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your name"
            android:text="@={userObservableField.name}"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="@{userObservableField.name.length()>0}"
            android:text="Proceed"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your name"
            android:text="@={userMutable.name}"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="@{userMutable.name.length()>0}"
            android:text="Proceed"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your name"
            android:text="@={userBaseObservable.name}"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="@{userBaseObservable.name.length()>0}"
            android:text="Proceed"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityLoginBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this); // necessary for LiveData to work
        binding.setUserObservableField(new UserObservableField());
        binding.setUserBaseObservable(new UserBaseObservable());
        binding.setUserMutable(new UserMutable());
    }

    public static class UserObservableField {
        private ObservableField<String> name = new ObservableField<>();

        public ObservableField<String> getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(ObservableField<String> name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }


    public static class UserBaseObservable extends BaseObservable {
        private String name;

        // necessary for updating button
        @Bindable
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
        }
    }


    public static class UserMutable {
        private MutableLiveData<String> name = new MutableLiveData<>();

        public MutableLiveData<String> getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(MutableLiveData<String> name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

I placed all models inside Activity. I tried to explain well, still you can make comment if you have any confusion.

#### Output

[image: output image]

Comment: None of these address my question. Android's data binding allows binding expression to reference *other widgets in the same layout* and react to changes in those widgets' properties. I am inquiring about a specific scenario for this (`EditText`) where it is not working as expected.

Comment: Hi sir, I am big fan of you :),  I did not get your problem. I thought your solution was not working for changing enable status of Button. Let me do some work again on your problem.

Comment: The code generated by the data binding framework is the same whether the binding expression is `foo.text.length > 0` or `foo.text.length() > 0`.

Comment: I also noticed this, but it makes difference with working. I tested both, it is working with `length()`

Comment: Aha! I see the difference now! With the `()`, the data binding correctly generates the `TextWatcher` to keep updating the enabled property -- without the `()`, those lines are not generated. I filed [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116536168) on this, as if the data binding compiler is smart enough to know to add `()` to the `length` for the method call, it should know to add the `TextWatcher`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I could also add something here, personally I don't like exposing mutable live data. Hence you can use `android:afterTextChanged` attribute and do something like `android:afterTextChanged="@{(text) -> viewmodel.onSomethingChanged(text)}"`. This way you don't expose your MutableLiveData object.